# Joining data in R by first row, then second and so on

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join, vlookup

I have two data sets with one common variable - ID (there are duplicate ID numbers in both data sets). I need to link dates to one data set, but I can't use left-join because the first or left file so to say needs to stay as it is (I don't want it to return all combinations and add rows). But I also don't want it to link data like vlookup in Excel which finds the first match and returns it so when I have duplicate ID numbers it only returns the first match. I need it to return the first match, then the second, then third (because the dates are sorted so that the newest date is always first for every ID number) and so on BUT I can't have added rows. Is there any way to do this? Since I don't know how else to show you  I have included an example picture of what I need. [data joining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsfNM.jpg). Not sure if I made myself clear but thank you in advance!

Comment: Kindly share the data and provide the reproducible example!

Comment: Do both datasets have the exact same amount of rows?

Comment: Do a left-join to create extra rows, then `spread` those extra rows into multiple variables so you end up with the same number of rows as your started in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a second column to create subid's that follow the order of the rownumbers. Then you can use an inner_join to join everything together.

Since you don't have example data sets I created two to show the principle.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(follow_id = row_number())


df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(follow_id = row_number())

outcome <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [?]
     ID sub_id var1 
  <dbl>  <int> <fct>
1     1      1 a    
2     1      2 b    
3     2      1 e    
4     3      1 f    
5     4      1 h    
6     4      2 i    
7     4      3 j
```

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2,3,4,4,4))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  var1 = letters[1:11])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a secondary id column. Since you need the first n matches, just group by the id, create an autoincrement id for each group, then join as usual

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4))
d1=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2012/01/01'), by="day"),11)
df2<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4),d1,d2=d1+sample.int(50,11))
library(dplyr)
df11 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(id2=1:n())%>%
  ungroup()
df21 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(id2=1:n())%>%
  ungroup()

left_join(df11,df21,by = c("id", "id2"))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     id   id2 d1         d2        
  <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1     1 2009-06-10 2009-06-13
2     1     2 2004-05-28 2004-07-11
3     2     1 2001-08-13 2001-09-06
4     3     1 2005-12-30 2006-01-19
5     4     1 2000-08-06 2000-08-17
6     4     2 2010-09-02 2010-09-10
7     4     3 2007-07-27 2007-09-05
```